# Rate limiting in Gazebo 1.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using earlier releases of gazebo with some success.  I'm currently experimenting with the 1.0 -RC3 version of gazebo to be included with fuerte, but I'm having trouble with rate limiting.

In the earlier versions placing the `<updateRate>` tag with a negative number would lock the simulation to real time.   A bit of investigation into the new system shows that adding an update rate to the ode like this:

```
<ode update_rate="1.0">
```

should limit the frame rate.  Despite experimenting with the values my rather simple simulation is still running at many times real time.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31148/rate-limiting-in-gazebo-1.0/) by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 586 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's an attribute under , see the [SDF documentation for Physics elements](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/sdf_physics), for example, the [empty world](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/hg/file/955ea031a5b2/sdf/worlds/empty.world) in gazebo is rate limited to 1000Hz with 1ms time step size, so effectively should track real-time.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-04-19**:
Thanks, that seems to have fixed the issue.